# Monte Carlo Approximation of a Normalizing Constant

Tags: bayesian, estimation, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, normalizing-constant

I know that one can approximate expectations of a function with respect to a pdf as such
$$
\mathbb{E}_{p(x)}[\phi(x)] = \int \phi(x) p(x) dx \approx \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \phi(x^{(i)}) \qquad\qquad \text{where } x^{(i)} \sim p(x)
$$
How can I approximate a normalizing constant in a similar way using Monte Carlo?
$$
\mathcal{Z} = \int \widetilde{p}(x) dx \approx \,\, ?
$$

Answer (score 1):

I would follow the same scheme as in importance sampling https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Importance_sampling, i.e I'll find a distribution $f(x)$ that I can easily sample from with the same domain as $\tilde{p}(x)$ and I'll approximate the normalizing constant as

$$Z = \int \tilde{p}(x)\frac{f(x)}{f(x)}dx= \int \frac{\tilde{p}(x)}{f(x)}f(x)dx \approx \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\tilde{p}(x^{(n)})}{f(x^{(n)})} \ , \ \ x^{(n)}\sim f(x)$$

Comment: The sum should be multiplied by $1/N$. E.g. if $\tilde{p} = f$ then the sum would be $N$ when it should be $1$